# How can I speed up sidereel.com using Chrome on my android TV PCs?

Tags: chrome-for-android, 7.1-nougat

I have several android TV PCs, all with the same apps and configurations. One use is watching streamed shows on TV. I use sidereal.com to keep up with my shows, but it takes forever for the site to load and navigate. These are 8x ARM Cortex-A53 CPUs running at 1000mhz, 2gb ram, android 7.1.2, rooted, Xposed framework.

If I view sidereal.com on a Windows machine or android phone, the site renders quickly. I understand the TV PCs are not going to work as well, but they should work better. Other sites viewed on the TV PCs work fine. For instance dailymail.co.uk works good, with a very long page scroll and much content. DickMorris.com and Facebook.com work excellent and play videos. I have no problem navigating or streaming Amazon, Hulu, or Netflix. For some reason sidereal.com does not work well on these devices.